# How to add line breaks in mail using contact form 7 wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add linebreaks in mail template using contact form 7. I googled it but cant find the apt solution.

**This is my mail template I just want to show the content in a paragraph wise. Any idea guys**
[My mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHZHw.png)

In my backend (wp-admin contact form 7 mail) i will give like this

```
       <tr>
            <td width="30%" style="padding:10px 15px;"><p style="font-size:14px;color:#878787;">Relevant Medical History: </p></td>
            <td width="70%"><p style="font-size:14px;color:#404346; padding:10px 15px;  font-weight:500;">[radio-344]</p></td>
      </tr> 

      <tr>
<td width="30%" style="padding:10px 15px;"><p style="font-size:14px;color:#878787;">Relevant Medical History: </p></td>
            <td width="100%" colspan="2" style="padding:10px 15px;"><p style="font-size:14px;color:#404346;"><br/><br/>[periododonticsmedhistory]</p></td>
     </tr>
```

> In my mail I add like this
>   [while adding paragraph in mail it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyKqB.png)
>
> Expected answer

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.*

Comment: what rules for deciding where these line breaks will go?

Comment: I didnt understand where thes line breaks go, but while sending email I added with line breaks. But in email line breaks are not showing.

Comment: did you add `\n`'s or `<br>`'s ?

Comment: no i didnt add that, Because how can we ask user to add \n's or <br>'s . any other idea sir

Comment: i asked if YOU added those, not the user. You said you added linre breaks a while ago, i'm asking which you added

Comment: sorry to say, I updated my question just have a look sir.

Comment: Ah! Try running `$value = nl2br($value)`, where value is the text area contents

Comment: while adding mail content. I added 3 paragraphs. But in mail its combining all 3 paragraphs into single paragraph.

Comment: where i have to try this [$value = nl2br($value)], because I didnt write any function in my functions.php

Comment: try my suggestion above

Comment: Just do it anywhere before sending the data to the email template. Obviously `$value` might be called something else, but you'll know what

Comment: In contact form 7 plugin it automatically send mail in my final submit, so where I have to add this data?

Comment: where do you call this plugin? when you hit submit, where does the code go?

Comment: yeah that i have already mentioned in my question sir, How exactly my code looks like

Comment: what's the form action url?

Comment: Sir please have a look, this is the exact issue i am facing now. https://www.seblod.com/community/forums/forms-content-types/textarea-line-breaks-in-e-mail-contact-form

Comment: that doesn't help. i write code, not configure other peoples plugins. What is the form action URL?

Comment: /referral-form-periodontics/ this is my form auction url

Comment: You can convert new line characters into `br` elements and set mail content to html. You can use filter or something in wordpress to add the call to `nl2br()`

Comment: ok sir let me try it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add br tag in html markup in where you want to see the line breaks. Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Follow these 2 simple steps, and you'll be good:

**1.** Add a `<textarea>` element to your contact form, not `<input type="text">`.

[image]

**2.** For the textarea element, please set the css styles required to preserve line-breaks.

```
textarea {
    white-space: pre-line !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `<pre>` tag, like so:

```
<pre>[your-textarea]</pre>
```

The line breaks will be preserved in your email.